# need to repeat the previous transaction at place of null

Tags: sql, oracle

**My store procedure:**

```
SELECT B.ETADATE,
  a.NAME,
  a.CATEGORY ,
  a.TYPE,
  a.STOCK
FROM
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS "FROM_DATE",
    NAME                                                      AS "NAME",
    CATEGORY                                                  AS "CATEGORY",
    TYPE                                                      AS "TYPE",
    BALANCE                                                   AS "BALANCE"
  FROM VW_NET_STOCK_POSITION
  ) a,
  (SELECT dt + LEVEL AS ETADate
  FROM
    (SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01-09-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM') - 1 AS dt
    FROM DUAL
    ) D
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - dt
  ) B
WHERE a.FROM_DATE(+) = B.ETADATE
ORDER BY ETADate;
```

**and my output is:**

[image]

but I want that where 'null' then there should be replaced with the previous transaction.

Like this,

**want output like this**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `+` for outer joins!  The solution to your problem is `LAG(. . . IGNORE NULLS)`.  But the query can be cleaned up.

I would suggest writing this as:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT (dt + level - 1) as etadate
      FROM (SELECT TRUNC(DATE '2018-09-01', 'MM') - 1 AS dt
            FROM DUAL
           ) d
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= sysdate - dt + 1  -- to get today's date
  ) 
SELECT d.etadate,
       COALESCE(nsp.name, LAG(nsp.name IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) as name,
       COALESCE(nsp.category, LAG(nsp.category IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate)) as category,
       COALESCE(LAG(nsp.type IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate), type) as type,
       COALESCE(LAG(nsp.stock IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY d.etadate), stock) as stock
FROM dates d LEFT JOIN
     VW_NET_STOCK_POSITION nsp
     ON d.etadate = TRUNC(nsp.from_date)
ORDER BY d.ETADate;
```

Comment: it's coming correctly but values are coming in next date, means value of 5th sept coming in 6th sept @Gordon Linoff

Comment: and also it's not including today's date

Comment: @KhushiCoder . . . Yes, of course.  If the column has a value in a row, then presumably you want that.  I fixed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `LAST_VALUE` analytical function with `IGNORE NULLS` option to make the *SQL* as follows :

```
SELECT ETADATE,
       LAST_VALUE(NAME)  IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY etadate) as NAME, 
       LAST_VALUE(CATEGORY) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY etadate) as CATEGORY,
       LAST_VALUE(TYPE) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY etadate ) as TYPE,
       LAST_VALUE(BALANCE) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY etadate ) as STOCK
  FROM 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS "FROM_DATE",
      NAME                                                      AS "NAME",
      CATEGORY                                                  AS "CATEGORY",
      TYPE                                                      AS "TYPE",
      BALANCE                                                   AS "BALANCE"
    FROM VW_NET_STOCK_POSITION
    ) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT dt + LEVEL AS ETADate
       FROM
      (SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01-09-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM') - 2 
           AS dt
      FROM DUAL
      ) D
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= trunc(sysdate) - dt
    ) B
   ON ( a.FROM_DATE = B.ETADATE )
ORDER BY ETADate;
```

and prefer using `ANSI JOIN` standard.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a0f16/1)

Comment: but the middle date is not there like, 3 sept, 4 sept, to 11 sept & 15 sept , 16 sept..i want that also  @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: @KhushiCoder I think you're asking for the values in the demo, I've expanded them.